# Sftp Channel "session is down"

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am running a Mule ESB which connects to the SFTP Server to move the files from working directory to another folder from where the files can be processed and data can be stored in DB.

Although I have never faced any connection issue, I received an error

```
1.  ERROR 2016-07-31 08:30:40,465 [[ISRESB].jmsActiveMQ.receiver.10] org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient: Error during login to abcd@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down
                at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.sendChannelOpen(Channel.java:667)
                at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:151)
                at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:145)
                at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient.login(SftpClient.java:142)
```

I believe this error could be because of too many open channels. But it'll be great if someone can help me why 'session is down' error occurs on a more minute scale.

Thank you

Comment: Would it be possible to add some of your code?

Comment: actually I got this from the logs file. Unfortunately I don't have access to the code. It's been compiled as a jar. So the connection logic is packaged.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. If this is not a programming question, you might be better of at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @Julian I am coding

Comment: @dodger: How this issue got fixed? We are also hitting with the same error in Mule ESB!

Comment: @HanuAthena we were closing the session and weren't re-opening  session. So close all open sessions and open a new session. That would resolve this issue.